# Session variable clears itself (PHP)

Tags: php, session, authentication

As a part of a very simple login script, I create a session variable (or at least that is what I think it's called) with the username, and use that as a check of whether or not a user is logged in. The variable is set in the login script, using the following code:

```
if($count==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ed_user'] = $ed_user;
    header("location:main.php");
} else {
    echo "Incorrect user or password, please try again.";
}
```

I know that the first part of this if-statement is run, since I am not presented with the error message. On the page it directs to (`main.php`) the first lines of code should check if `$_SESSION['ed_user']` is set, and return to `index.php`, if this is not the case. This is done with the code:

```
if(!$_SESSION['ed_user']){
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

However, it seems to always return me to index.php after login. I have tried to check if the variable exists, using the following line:

```
<p><?php echo"Current user: ".$_SESSION['ed_user'];?></p>
```

Which indicates that the variable is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
session_start();
```

On every page.

Comment: Well that seems somewhat counter-intuitive, but thanks :-). It is working now.

Comment: @Noceo: no worries, sessions are a pain.

Answer (score 1):

On your `main.php` file...

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ed_user'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

You need to call `session_start()` to access session variables.